# login form using jsp and servlets without DBMS

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to create a login form for a blog system. I have completed the login form using jsp, now i need to use a servlet to process the login details. However the tutorial i am following uses a dbms to query the form details and authenticate a user. How can i go about this WITHOUT using a database?

this is the tutorial i am following, 
http://www.ganeshtechblog.in/2013/09/creating-simple-login-form-using-eclipse.html

Comment: Use another data source for your data, like a file or a simple array with the valid users and their passwords, until you will use a real data source.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a local database ? TIP: XAMPP

or you can hardcode the user id and pw in your servlet.

You can make them as following:
    @ the top of your servlet add:

```
 private static final String ID="idvalue",PW="pwvalue";
```

Then

```
 String userId = request.getParameter("userId");
 String password = request.getParameter("pwd");
```

You get those two values from your View...
Now you just have to simply check if they are correct witht the hard coded ones...

```
if(userId.equals(ID) && password.equals(PW)){
            // fetch the session from request, create new session if session
            // is not present in the request
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); 
            session.setAttribute("FirstName", rs.getString("firstname"));
            session.setAttribute("LastName", rs.getString("lastname"));
            // redirect to success page
            response.sendRedirect("LoginSuccess.jsp"); 
}else{ // redirect to error page
            response.sendRedirect("LoginFailure.jsp");
}
```

I wouldn't use it as a real application though...

PS. this is one simple solution, there are many better way's...